# Ubuntu Studio 20.04, getting Pulse Audio and JACK to play nice

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, jack

I have seen similar questions from 5 years ago or more, so I'm not sure what the current solutions are. I have an audio setup on Arch using Cadence and have Pulse and JACK playing nice together. When I look into installing Cadence on US 20.04, it wants to remove a bunch of installed packages (including Studio Controls). So, before I try that and mess up all these nice tools that Ubuntu Studio has provided, I'd like to know:

If anyone is using Ubuntu Studio 20.04 with JACK and Pulse Audio together, can you tell me how you did it? Thanks.

Comment: Use `Studio Control` to start jack, everything is preconfigured and works out of the box.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was hoping. But it doesn't work. I'm wondering if it's because I'm not using an external Audio interface. All I'm trying to do is record using my laptop's internal mic (which works), and play using the laptop's internal speakers (which does not). It's as if I can route audio in and Pulse steps out of the way and lets JACK do it, but the output doesn't go from JACK back to Pulse. Either that, or JACK can't get directly to my speakers.

Answer (score 0):

If you scroll down in this blog post, it says how to use both together: https://www.fossbox.org.uk/?p=240

> By default, Jack and Pulse can’t normally run at the same time. However, as our web browser is a Pulse app and we wish to use Jack for routing, we’ll need to overcome that. One relatively easy route to achieving this uses QJackctl. In settings, under the option tab, go to Execute Script after startup. Paste in `pactl load-module module-jack-sink channels=2; pactl load-module module-jack-source channels=2; pacmd set-default-sink jack_out`.

> This will create two separate Pulse channels, called “sinks”.

> Once you’ve changed the settings, you’ll want to test if things have worked. Start Jack and then open any normal audio application such as your mp3 player. Try playing some sound. If you hear anything, it worked.

> Now, if you’re using a pro audio application like SuperCollider, PD or Reaper, go start it and turn on the Audio engine. In Qjackctl, click on connections and open the Audio tab. You’ll see a list of inputs and outputs on your system, including your audio application, the pulse sinks, and the system (ie, the physical inputs and outputs).

Use `Qjackctl` to draw connections between the sinks and your Jack applications.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Happy New Year. It's a frustrating experience. Ubuntu Studio 20.04 provides Studio Controls, yet I have to do this Execute Script stuff in qjackctl. AND, it still doesn't do what I'd like. When I have my audio interface connected, this solution does seem to work, thanks. When I remove my audio interface however and am back to using my built-in speakers, I have to shut JACK off, or I have no sound. There seems to be no way for me to keep JACK running and be able to switch between my built-in audio hardware or my USB audio interface dynamically. Clunky, but workable.

Comment: Jack doesn't deal well with change, so you would have to stop and start it again when you switch hardware configurations.  While this is annoying, it should switch gracefully between going with the sound card and going with the internal audio card.  I don't think this would restore any connections you made via the GUI, however.

If you feel like my answer is the the answer, I'd appreciate it if you'd click the checkmark next to it.